# MATLAB: All combinations of sum of vectors

Tags: matlab, combinations

So I have this piece of code (in MATLAB)

```
% Define vectorfield
 g1=[5,0,0];
 g2=[0,3,0];
 g3=[0,0,4];

% Define on-off
 u=[0;1];

% Define set to make field symmetric
symm=[1;-1];
k=1;

%% Generate possible combinations of vector fields
for a=1:length(u)
 for b=1:length(symm)
   for c=1:length(u)
     for d=1:length(symm)
       for e=1:length(u)
         for f=1:length(symm)
           allvecfields(k,:)=u(a).*symm(b).*g1+u(c).*symm(d).*g2+u(e).*symm(f).*g3;
           k=k+1;
         end
       end
     end
   end
 end
end

realfields=transpose(unique(allvecfields,'rows'));
```

Each column of `realfields` is a unique positive, negative or zero combination of the `g`'s. I need some help generalizing this. That is the size of each `g` can be `n`, and the number of `g`'s can be `m`. The code should still return all the unique possible combinations of the `g`'s. I have a feeling that recursion will have to be used but all my attempts have failed so far.

Also `allvecfields(k,:)` just means kth row, all columns. Even if your answer contains C/C++ or Java code (without any special functions from them) that is fine for me. I will translate it into MATLAB.

I have looked at `combvec` and the `allcomb` file but they don't do what I need.  For example `transpose(unique(combvec(g1,g2,g3,-g1,-g2,-g3)','rows'))` returns a 6x63 matrix not the 3x27 that I want. Doing

```
vals=transpose(unique(combvec(g1,g2,g3)','rows'));
vals=[vals transpose(unique(combvec(-g1,g2,g3)','rows'))];
vals=[vals transpose(unique(combvec(g1,-g2,g3)','rows'))];
vals=[vals transpose(unique(combvec(g1,g2,-g3)','rows'))];
vals=[vals transpose(unique(combvec(g1,-g2,-g3)','rows'))];
vals=[vals transpose(unique(combvec(-g1,g2,-g3)','rows'))];
vals=[vals transpose(unique(combvec(-g1,-g2,g3)','rows'))];
vals=[vals transpose(unique(combvec(-g1,-g2,-g3)','rows'))];
vals=unique(vals','rows');
```

Does give what I want, but that does not help in generalizing.

**EDIT:** Fixed error in last line of first code block. The required output for this case is quite large (27 columns) but if we just had `g1` and `g2` then the output would be:

```
realfields =

-5    -5    -5     0     0     0     5     5     5
-3     0     3    -3     0     3    -3     0     3
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

**EDIT**: Based on a suggestion in the comments, I have been able to rewrite the above code as,

```
u=[-1,0,1];
k=1;
for a=1:length(u)
  for b=1:length(u)
    for c=1:length(u)
        uMat(k,:)=[u(a) u(b) u(c)];
        k=k+1;
    end
  end
end

g1=[5,0,0];
g2=[0,3,0];
g3=[0,0,4];
gMat=[g1' g2' g3'];

for a=1:size(uMat,1)
    allvecfields(k,:)=sum(bsxfun(@times,gMat,uMat(a,:)),2);
end

realfields=transpose(unique(allvecfields,'rows'))
```

I think this is slightly more elegant but I am still stuck at how to dynamically generate `uMat` given the number of columns in `gMat`. I can't believe a function doesn't exist for this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The desired output got your input would help.

Comment: I think if you stack all `g` in a matrix and also create a vector with the products of `u` and `symm`, that might take you in the right direction and make the code efficient too.

Comment: Note that transpose is simply `.'`

Comment: I know, I wrote it as transpose() so that non MATLAB users aren't left out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution

```
g1=[5,0,0];
g2=[0,3,0];
g3=[0,0,4];

gMat=[g1' g2' g3'];

m=size(gMat',1);
allvecfields = zeros(3^m,m);

for k = 1:3^m
 allvecfields(k,:) = double(dec2base(k-1,3,m)-'1');
end

realfields = (allvecfields*gMat')'
```

Credits to: [Roger Stafford](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/profile/authors/1187260-roger-stafford) for this ingenious solution.